# How can I convert string to Guid?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, guid

I have string type value like `"e2ddfa02610e48e983824b23ac955632"`. I need to add - in this code means convert in Guid.

```
EntityKey = "e2ddfa02610e48e983824b23ac955632";
Id = (Guid)paymentRecord.EntityKey;
```

Comment: Which one is it? C# or C++(CLI)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just a simple creation:

```
  String source = "e2ddfa02610e48e983824b23ac955632";

  Guid result = new Guid(source);
```

Comment: Id = new Guid(paymentRecord.EntityKey),   with this a error is coming "cannot convert object to byte[]"

Comment: @Kapil Garg: what is the type of `paymentRecord.EntityKey`? i.e. `paymentRecord.EntityKey.GetType().Name`?

Answer (score 9):

You could do :

```
Guid guid;
if (Guid.TryParse("e2ddfa02610e48e983824b23ac955632", out guid))
{
    // succeed...
}
else
{
    // failed...
}
```

Edit : Like @Silvermind said, if you know the format of the input, you can use `Guid.TryParseExact` with the `"N"` format in your case.

Comment: Since you know the format `"N"`, I would suggest adding it.

Answer (score 2):

For parsing the `string` to a `Guid`. You can do this:

```
var guid= "e2ddfa02610e48e983824b23ac955632";
var result= Guid.ParseExact(guid,"N")
```

Or if you prefer to have it in a try parse. You can also do this:

```
Guid result;
if(Guid.TryParseExact(guid,"N",out result))
{
    //Do something
}
```

The "N" is a format which indicates that the string will be format with 32 digits without "-"

**Reference:**

- [Guid.TryParseExact Method (String, String, Guid)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)